# Как добавить переменные в массив ?

Tags: javascript

имею переменные с данными

```
count=54 и number=23
```

нужно их соединить в один массив 'a'

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать литерал массива

```
var a = [count, number];
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
var a = [];
a.push(count);
a.push(number);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var a = {
    'count': count,
    'number':number
};
```

Comment: в вопросе речь идет о массиве, а в ответе получается объект